# Why is [TestClass]'s constructor called multiple times for each [TestMethod]?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

In case of you have multiple test method on a test class. Class's constructor is going to run multiple times. How we can explain this overload?

Comment: MSTest creates a new instance of the test class for every test method by-design. Reference https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/360#issuecomment-281347751

Comment: It would help if you added *which* unit testing framework you're talking about, and a brief example of the test fixture you're referring to.

Comment: There is also this question with the exact same title as your question from MSDN https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e7aa4c1-4e1d-4781-acf2-85543b94055a/why-is-testclasss-constructor-called-for-each-testmethod that essentially says the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding of MSTest, the test class gets instantiated for each `[TestMethod]`. I'm guessing you are attempting to run configuration code before any of the tests are ran. If that's the case I'd recommend you:

A) update your question to explain what it is exactly you would like to accomplish

B) make use of the `[ClassInitialize]` attribute to mark a method to be ran once and only once before any of the class's tests are ran

**What Does ClassInitialize Do**

`ClassInitialize` is one of the many attributes available when using MSTest to write unit tests in C#. The more common ones include `TestClass`, `TestMethod`, and `TestInitialize`. This one indicates that the method should be ran once before running any of the methods marked with `TestMethod`. There's another attribute that goes hand-in-hand with it called `ClassCleanup` which gets ran after all of the test methods get ran.

You can read more details about these and more attributes at [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-members-in-unit-tests?view=vs-2017)

Comment: I'll provide the sanitized version of my unit test. Do you mean using [TestInitialize]?

Comment: I added some more details to my answer

Comment: Did this information help you resolve your issue? If so, please accept this as the Answer, else let me know what else is causing confusion.

Comment: I'm not able to find the reason. What is the benefit of constructor on test classes if their life time is limited to method life time?

Comment: I would recommend not using a constructor on your test classes. Anything that you would like to do in the constructor can be accomplished through the `TestInitialize` or `ClassInitialize` methods

Answer (score 1):

From induction on the internet, the constructor is called on each test.

[image]

If `TestInitialize` is **always** called after the constructor and
**called for each test**, by induction; the constructor is called
on each test.

Here is the link for the above image and article: [Use the MSTest framework in unit tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-members-in-unit-tests?view=vs-2022#test)
**below is the text**

> Test
> TestInitialize is called right before your test is started and [TestCleanup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcleanupattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)
> is called right after your test is finished.
>
> The `TestInitialize` is similar to the class constructor but is usually more suitable
> for long or async initializations.The `TestInitialize` is always called after
> the constructor and called for each test (including each data row of data-driven tests).

Use the constructor when:

1. Code is duplicated between the `constructor` and `[TestInitialize]` method
2. There are `private readonly` fields that need to be initialized in the constructor.
3. Multiple `[TestMethod]`s share fields in the test class

```cs
namespace Example.Tests;

[TestClass]
public class ExampleTests
{
    private readonly object _fieldOne;
    private readonly object _fieldTwo;

    public ExampleTests() // Runs for each test
    {
        _fieldOne = new object();
        _fieldTwo = new object();
    }

    //[TestInitialize]
    //public void Initialize()
    //{
    //    _fieldOne = new object();
    //    _fieldTwo = new object();
    //}

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Method1_Input_Output() { ... }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Method2_Input_Output() { ... }
}
```